# Conditionally create objects of different classes

Tags: c#, class, object, dynamic, types

I want to achieve something with other classes but I will provide an example, which is similar to mine. Suppose we have the following classes and the enum Gender:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2
}

public abstract class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Woman : Human
{
    public bool Intuition { get; set; }
}

public class Man : Human
{
    public bool Logic { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I want a class Meeting that uses an array of visitors (Human), which can be either Man or Woman objects. The array will contain objects of one of the two classes, depending on the value of the Gender enum provided. So, I can do something like this:

```
public class Meeting
{
    private Human[] visitors;
    public Human[] Visitors { get { return visitors; } set { visitors = value; } }

    public Meeting(Gender gender, int number)
    {
        if (gender == Gender.Male)
        {
            // If the gender is Male, create a new array of Man objects.
            visitors = new Man[number];
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, create a new array of Woman objects.
            visitors = new Woman[number];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            if (gender == Gender.Male)
            {
                // If the gender is Male, create a new Man object.
                visitors[i] = new Man();
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, create a new Woman object.
                visitors[i] = new Woman();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code is syntactically correct but I think it's not a well-written one. Suppose I had not only the Woman and Man classes, but for example 10 more classes. Moreover, suppose I had not two, but a thousand lines of code where I should create a new instance of the class, depending on some condition (in my case the value of the Gender enum).

Is there a better way to achieve this? For example, some sort of a class/variable which is assigned in the beginning of the method, depending on a value (enum) and is then used everywhere else.

**Should I use Generics in this situation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a good case for use of generics.You can do something like this:

```
public class Meeting<T> where T : Human, new()
{
    private T[] visitors;

    public T[] Visitors
    {
        get { return visitors; }
        set { visitors = value; }
    }

    public Meeting(int number)
    {
        visitors = new T[number];
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            visitors[i] = new T();
        }
    }
}
```

Also you won't need the `Gender` enumeration if you use generics.Here is the usage:

```
Meeting<Man> m = new Meeting<Man>(10);

m.Visitors[0].Name = "Jack";

Console.WriteLine(m.Visitors[0].Name);
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution

- I would use a generic factory. This removes the need for the enum type. Also a reason to add the factory is that in case the construction of a human involves extra work, this can be done in the factory, and it will not be scattered in multiple places in your solution.
- As I see it your instanced array is a specialized type, but it can be of the base type. This eliminates your first if-statement. You are exposing your array as an array-of-Humans anyway.
- Add some LINQ to ease the loop.

This results in the following:

```
public class HumanFactory {
    public T Create<T>() where T: Human, new() {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class Meeting<T> where T: Human {
    public T[] Visitors { get; set; }

    public Meeting(int number) {
        var humanFactory = new HumanFactory();
        Visitors = Enumerable.Range(1, number)
            .Select(x => humanFactory.Create<T>())
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By making sure that you have the name of Enum members same as your class names. You can use this approach

```
 public enum Gender
    {
        Men,Women
    }
    public class Human
    { 
    }
    class Men : Human
    {
    }
    class Women : Human
    {
    }

    class Meeting
    {
        List<Human> visitors = new List<Human>();

        public Meeting(Gender m, int Number)
        {
            string ClassName ="YourNameSpace."+ m.ToString();
            Type type = Type.GetType(ClassName);
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            for(int i=0; i<Number; i++)
            {
            visitors.Add(instance as Human);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix Polymorphism and Enums. They both serve the same purpose with Polymorphism being the more Open/Closed solution.

In this case I think your problem is your abstraction:

Your Men have Logic and your Women have Intuition, your abstraction might be `ISolveProblem` where the Men implementation use Logic to solve the problem and women use their Intuition.

This way, you don't need long switch or if/else statements (ie 10 possibilities) but can just loop through the Array and execute the `SolveProblem` method without regard to the actual Type of 'Human'.